# How can i check if i have already logged in salesforce in android application?

Tags: android, salesforce

Situation: 
1. i have user login form which is used by user to login into application, at the same time we login into salesforce.
2. next time when user opens the application then he is not supposed to get the login form,but directly the main screen.
3. in this main screen i have a button call sync which retrieves data from SF, but for that i have to check if i am already logged in SF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using oAuth you probably should look at using that instead. However, assuming that you're not, why not just try and make a request for the user's own user record using the session ID you have, and if that fails because the session ID is invalid then you can do the login again?

There's likely to be a way of testing other than by doing this, so I'd encourage you to read the documents for the API.

Comment: ConnectorConfig parameters = new ConnectorConfig("username",
   "password", null);
try {
     Salesforce.login(parameters, new SForceLoginResponseListener());
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

Please pardon, i was not able to use the tags.
@LaceySnr : I have done the login as mentioned above. Can you please explain me with a code snippet what you are saying.

Comment: @dreamer from there you would need to add the logic to deal with the response in your SForceLoginResponseListener class. It should contain onComplete/onSforceError/onException methods to deal with successful/erroneous login requests.

Once you have a successful login, I would keep track of this in some kind of session object, and then call finish() on the activity. Then, in the onResume() method of your main screen, check if the session is valid, and if so, redirect to the activity with your sync button.

Comment: @JCD yes i was thinking in the same way but what will happen if i have closed my application after loging in once into application, so now application will not show the login form and will directly show the main screen. NOW what will be the situation am i logged in SF or do i have to do it again.

Comment: @dreamer assuming you've closed the app without killing the process, your session information would still be stored in memory in the "some kind of session object" that I mentioned. When going back into the app, `onResume()` would be called, where you could check to see if you have an active session. Probably the easiest way to determine if the session is still valid is to run a simple query using the session ID you have stored, as LaceySnr mentioned.